# Undefined symbol, despite being defined in linked library (CUDA 10.1)

Tags: python, c++, linker, shared-libraries

I have a library `my_lib.so` which links to several CUDA 10.1 libraries, including `libnppicc.so`.

Running `ldd` on the library outputs the following - all dependencies are resolved correctly:

```
12:51:45 ~/ $ ldd my_lib.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffc5183000)
        libopenblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007f8bdbb00000)
        librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f8bdbaf6000)
        libomp.so => /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libomp.so (0x00007f8bdba0d000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f8bdb9ec000)
        libcudnn.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7 (0x00007f8bc5100000)
        libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f8bc50f9000)
        libcudart.so.10.1 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.1 (0x00007f8bc4e33000)
        libcublas.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.10 (0x00007f8bc1098000)
        libcufft.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so.10 (0x00007f8bb2d34000)
        libcusolver.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.10 (0x00007f8ba8229000)
        libcurand.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so.10 (0x00007f8ba32f9000)
        libnppicc.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicc.so.10 (0x00007f8ba2cba000)
        libnppial.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppial.so.10 (0x00007f8ba1f67000)
        libnppist.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppist.so.10 (0x00007f8ba0b11000)
        libnppidei.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppidei.so.10 (0x00007f8ba0121000)
        libnppig.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppig.so.10 (0x00007f8b9e64f000)
        libnppitc.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppitc.so.10 (0x00007f8b9e165000)
        libnpps.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnpps.so.10 (0x00007f8b9d6de000)
        libnvToolsExt.so.1 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnvToolsExt.so.1 (0x00007f8b9d4d5000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f8b9d351000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f8b9d1ce000)
        libmvec.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmvec.so.1 (0x00007f8b9d1a2000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f8b9d188000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f8b9cfc5000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f8c3990d000)
        libgfortran.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x00007f8b9cd57000)
        libcublasLt.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublasLt.so.10 (0x00007f8b9aeb3000)
        libnppc.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppc.so.10 (0x00007f8b9ac38000)
        libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f8b9abf4000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f8b9a9d6000)
```

Next, I have a python bindings library which correctly links against this shared library `lib_tf.so`.
When I try to run a simple python program which imports the python module, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    import myLib
ImportError: /home/Jim/my_python_bindings_lib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: nppiGammaInv_8u_C3IR
```

So we are getting an undefined symbol error to `nppiGammaInv_8u_C3IR`.
The strange thing is that this symbol is defined in `libnppicc.so` which is being linked.

We can confirm this is the case by running `nm`:

```
12:51:53 ~/$ nm -D /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libnppicc.so.10 | gr
ep nppiGammaInv_8u_C3IR
0000000000090590 T nppiGammaInv_8u_C3IR
00000000000907b0 T nppiGammaInv_8u_C3IR_Ctx
```

Why am I getting this error when the symbol has a definition?
What's stranger is that when I run the same test script & libs on other machines with CUDA 10.1 installed, it works fine. So something is wrong with this specific machine, but I can't figure out what. I also have cuda 11.1 installed on this machine, not sure if that's relevant.

**Edit**

Someone suggested I also run `ldd` on the python bindings library, so here it is:

```
09:49:10 ~/ $ ldd my_python_bindings_lib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd3f79c000)
        my_lib.so => /home/Jim/my_lib.so (0x00007f5a522f4000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f5a522c3000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f5a522a2000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f5a5211e000)
        libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f5a51f9b000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f5a51f7f000)
        libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f5a51dbe000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f5ab0bd0000)
        libopenblas.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblas.so.0 (0x00007f5a4fbda000)
        librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f5a4fbd0000)
        libomp.so => /usr/lib/llvm-7/lib/libomp.so (0x00007f5a4fae7000)
        libcudnn.so.7 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudnn.so.7 (0x00007f5a391fb000)
        libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f5a391f4000)
        libcudart.so.10.1 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.10.1 (0x00007f5a38f2e000)
        libcublas.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.10 (0x00007f5a35193000)
        libcufft.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcufft.so.10 (0x00007f5a26e2f000)
        libcusolver.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda-10.1/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so.10 (0x00007f5a1c324000)
        libcurand.so.10 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcurand.so.10 (0x00007f5a173f2000)
        libnvToolsExt.so.1 => /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libnvToolsExt.so.1 (0x00007f5a171e9000)
        libgfortran.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x00007f5a16f7b000)
        libcublasLt.so.10 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublasLt.so.10 (0x00007f5a150d7000)
        libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f5a15093000)
        libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f5a14e75000)
```

Comment: The undefined reference comes from `my_python_bindings_lib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`, not `my_lib.so`. What is the `ldd` output for the former?

Comment: @EmployedRussian I edited my answer to include the requested information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing a Python module, which depends on `my_python_bindings_lib.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`.

That library:

1. has unresolved symbol `nppiGammaInv_8u_C3IR` (defined in `libnppicc`), and
2. does *not* depend on `libnppicc.so.10` where the symbol is defined.

It is exceedingly likely that `my_python_bindings_lib` *should* depend on `libnppicc` (since it uses a symbol defined there), and that adding that dependency will fix your `import` problem.